# Perl6 Redis stuck when ask for output

Tags: redis, raku

For some unknown reason (not even in Redis log), this piece of code will stuck forever... Please help..

```
use v6;
use Redis;

my $redis = Redis.new("127.0.0.1:6379");
$redis.auth("xxxxxxxxx");
$redis.set("key", "value");
say $redis.get("key");
say $redis.info();
$redis.quit();
```

Comment: I've not used the Redis module before so don't know off the top of my head. Do you know *where* it sticks?

Comment: right before 'get'. if i comment out both 'get' and 'info', the program will finish

Comment: What are the `auth` and `set` calls returning?

Comment: bool value. In this case, both 1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wonder if the issue is because the Redis library is a bit old and there's been a few changes to the runtime in the intervening time.

Have you tried [Redis::Async](https://github.com/CurtTilmes/perl6-eredis)? It seems more up to date.

Comment: yup. I ended up using Redis Async